# Has the legal status of Jesus Christ every come up in court?

Tags: international, religion, reference-request

This Easter weekend, we celebrate the resurrection of Jesus Christ. That being said, in the public sphere, the question of whether this resurrection has actually occurred is a heated one.

Life and death is not only a religious, but also a legal issue. So, my question is, **are there any cases in which the question of whether Jesus Christ rose from the dead on the third day has been brought up in a court of law**?

Note: I don't expect a court to have answered this question. I'm just wondering if it has ever been brought up as important question in the case.

Comment: By "ever", do you mean "in the last 2,000 years"? Also, what do you mean by "court of law"? Also, jurisdiction? The answer is probably "yes", unless you reign in the scope of the question.

Comment: I understand St Paul (aka Saul of Tarsus) argued the point before several courts, and was granted permission to appeal to Caesar (the highest earthly authority). Sadly the transcripts do not appear to be extant.

Answer (score 2):

There have been many courts that have inquired into the nature of divinity, mainly ecclesiastical ones. On the basis of their results we can say that Jesus did rise because the heretic who said he didn’t was executed. Please note that courts have been known to make mistakes.